# Why we get area under curve when function goes infinity between limits?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Why we get area under curve of definite integral between limits where function goes to infinity using substitution method.

e.g : $$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sec(x).\tan(x) \space dx $$
 Function goes to infinity  between these limits.why we get area under curve?

Comment: Most often, the "area under curve" is *defined* using the integral, so you get the "area under curve" *by definition*. If your definition of "area under curve" is different/independent on the integral, could you please state it?

Comment: Yes we compute using definite integral. That's why i written integral. But the curve is gone infinity between interval so why we get area under curve of this function using integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to give some background here, hope this will help the OP to understand what is going on with this curve and this integral.

First, "area under curve" is a vague concept until defined rigorously. Let's not get into the intricacies of [Jordan measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure) and [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure), but if the curve is defined by a non-negative function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$, then it turns out that:

- If $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$ (which implies it is bounded), then the Jordan measure of "area under curve" exists and is equal to $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ ([Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral))
- If $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable on $[a,b]$, then the Lebesgue measure of "area under curve" exists (even though it can be infinite), and it is equal to $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ ([Lebesgue integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration))

As it happens, Riemann integral is simpler to teach (and is so usually introduced first to students), but is more restricted in terms of when it can be calculated. For one thing, it requires the function to be bounded, which your function certainly isn't. (Your function is $f(x)=\sec x\cdot\tan x=\frac{\sin x
}{\cos^2 x}$ and, as you've noticed, $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f(x)dx=+\infty$). You can still use Lebesgue integral, or you can use the sum of the improper Riemann (or Lebesgue) integrals: $\int_0^{\pi/2-0}f(x)dx+\int_{\pi/2+0}^\pi f(x)dx$. Both approaches can be proven to give you the same result.

Now, as $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ is the primitive function of your function, it follows that $\int_a^b \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}dx=\frac{1}{\cos x}\mid_a^b=\frac{1}{\cos b}-\frac{1}{\cos a}$ on any interval where your function is defined and Riemann-integrable ([Fundamental theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)). This *precludes* intervals such as $[0,\pi]$, but still lets us calculate the improper integrals:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2-0}f(x)dx=\lim_{b\to\pi/2-0}\left(\frac{1}{\cos b}-\frac{1}{\cos 0}\right)=+\infty$$
$$\int_{\pi/2+0}^\pi f(x)dx=\lim_{a\to\pi/2+0}\left(\frac{1}{\cos \pi}-\frac{1}{\cos a}\right)=+\infty$$

and so, by adding up those two numbers, the final integral diverges, i.e. its value is $+\infty$, which also means that the area under the curve is infinite.

(At least, this happens with the function from your question... You can think of another function, say $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{|\cos x|}}$, for which the improper integrals would be finite and their sum would give you a finite "area under curve" - give it a try!)

Note a common mistake one can make: to calculate

$$\int_0^\pi f(x)dx=\frac{1}{\cos x}]_0^\pi=\frac{1}{\cos \pi}-\frac{1}{\cos 0} = 1-1 = 0$$

This is obviously not just incorrect but doesn't make any sense (as the curve is obviously "above" the $x$-axis, the area "under" it cannot end up being zero!), but as pointed above the mistake is that one has used the Fundamental theorem of Calculus on an interval where that theorem does not apply.

Comment: hello @Stinking Bishop. Is it necessary to calculate Integral in pieces when function has infinity between interval. e.g: $ \int_{0}^{\pi} \sec(x) \cdot \tan(x) $ is incorrect.

Comment: Pls confirm. Means for functions which has infinity between interval e.g: $ \int_{0}^{\pi}  \tan(x) $ is incorrect to find integral " Area under curve " . We need to calculate this way $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} tan(x) + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} tan(x)$

Comment: If the function has an infinity, you *have to use improper integrals*. Whether sometimes you would also get the correct result the other way or not, doesn't matter too much. (I guess sometimes you might, most often you won't!) After all, in maths you need to show your works and it isn't just the end result that matters, but *how* you got it.

Comment: In case of functions asked in question it is always necessary to use improper integral? and if  infinity between interval." area under curve " is $ \infty $ .

Comment: @123 If by "my functions" you mean "non-negative functions on an interval that are not Riemann-integrable but where the interval can be broken up into finitely many subintervals such that you can calculate improper Riemann integrals on each of them", then yes, it is necessary. The actual area under curve will be calculated as a sum of those improper integrals, and may end up being finite or infinite.

Comment: If function is divergent between interval and result is finite, means these result is incorrect?

Comment: If the function goes to infinity, it just means *you need to use improper integrals to calculate "area under curve"*. It does *not* preclude a finite result. The area under curve may end up being finite even if that area "stretches to infinity", as this area gets thinner and thinner the "higher" you go. (Such things should have stopped puzzling you ever since you realised that $1+1/2+1/4+1/8+\ldots =2<\infty$ and that Zeno's paradox is not really a paradox.)

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry (i.e. by applying the substitution $x\mapsto \pi-x$ on the integration range $(\pi/2,\pi]$)
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\,dx=2\left[\frac{1}{\cos x}\right]_{0}^{\pi/2} $$
is divergent. On the other hand
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{\left[\cos^2(x)\right]^a}\,dx = \frac{2}{1-2a} $$
for any $a<\frac{1}{2}$.

A function doesn't need to be bounded to be improperly Riemann integrable. Think to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ over $(0,1]$, for instance.

Comment: How do we know function and limit is symmetric?

Comment: @123: $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$ and $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos(x)$.

Comment: But, once again the function $ \textbf{sec(x).tan(x)} $ or $\textbf{ \frac{2.sin(x)}{ cos^2(x)}}$ at $\pi /2$ goes to infinity. Why answer is some number area under curve. Not infinity.

Comment: It is infinity though? Jack's shown that the integral is divergent. It would be a finite area if the discontinuity rapidly approached infinity but it doesn't.

Comment: @123: I have already answered that. For the area under the curve to be finite, a function does not need to be bounded. Still $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$ is both unbounded and not integrable over $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: hello all, Is it possible using only algebra (not substitution method which required differentiation) can we make new function of $\mathbf{sec(x).tan(x)}$ with multiple terms. As all individual terms are bounded within $\mathbf{[0 , \pi]}$ interval.

Answer (score 1):

See [Math HWS: Improper Integrals with Infinite Discontinuities](http://math.hws.edu/mitchell/Math131S13/tufte-latex/Improper2.pdf). Ordinarily, when $f$ has an infinite discontinuity at $a$ or $b$, the integral $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is defined with the *limit* as the bounds approach $a$ or $b$, e.g., $\displaystyle \int_a^{b-\varepsilon} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ as $\varepsilon\to0$. Then when there is an infinite discontinuity at $c\in(a,b)$, you'd split the integral into $\displaystyle \int_a^c f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_c^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and treat each integral with the previous rule. For example, in the case of $\displaystyle f(x)=-\ln(x^2)$ on $[-1,1]$, which has a discontinuity at $0$ that rapidly approaches $+\infty$, you would have

$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \left[
\int_{-1}^{0-\varepsilon}
-\ln(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_{0+\varepsilon}^{1}
-\ln(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x
\right]
\\
=\lim \left(\left[-x (\ln(x^2)-2)\right]_{-1}^{-\varepsilon}
+\left[-x (\ln(x^2)-2)\right]_{\varepsilon}^1\right)
\\
=\lim \left(2\varepsilon\left(\ln\left(\varepsilon^{2}\right)-2\right)+4\right)
\\
=4$$

Since the functions inside the limit are being integrated over continuous intervals and the limit exists, the integral is finite despite the discontinuity. However, if we tried this in the case of $f(x)=\sec x\tan x$ we would see that the limit does not exist since the function's discontinuity doesn't approach $+\infty$ quickly enough.

Comment: hello all, if the function is divergent and integral (area under curve) is finite of that function. How can we say the result of area is correct? What is the interpretation of definite integral of such curves?

Comment: If the integral were finite (which it *isn't* in your case), we'd know the area via the method in my answer.

Comment: hello @Jam . What is the interpretation when integral is finite and function is divergent in some interval?